# Delphi XE3 TStatusBar Redraw

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I cannot seem to get the status bar to update/refresh/redraw:

```
  TopFormmlcmpStatusPanel1.Invalidate;
  SendMessage(TopFormmlcmpStatusPanel1.Handle, WM_PAINT, WParam(0), LParam(0));
```

In another scenario I have tried:

```
 SendMessage(TopFormmlcmpStatusPanel1.Handle, WM_ERASEBKGND, WParam(0), LParam(0));
```

I just want to redraw the statusbar with the updated colors.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `TopFormmlcmpStatusPanel1` is of type `TStatusBar`.

You do not send `WM_PAINT` or `WM_ERASEBKGND` messages. The system does that.

Your code:

```
TopFormmlcmpStatusPanel1.Invalidate;
```

will lead to a new paint cycle. When the message loop is next emptied, a paint cycle will be generated and the control will be re-painted.

Alternatively you might use:

```
TopFormmlcmpStatusPanel1.Refresh;
```

if you want the control to be re-painted immediately.

So, I guess your problem is more subtle than you think. My expectation is that your controls are drawn by the system using the system theme. And your attempts to change the colour simply cannot ever have any effect because the theme overrides the control's colour properties. Without an SSCCE, it is hard to be sure that this is the problem.

---

In the comments you state that your control is owner drawn. It is conceivable that your owner draw code has a fault. I am clearly in no position to comment on that code which I cannot observe. However, I would re-state the fact that the `Invalidate` and `Refresh` methods will both lead to a paint cycle.

Comment: The status bar was produced via owner draw.

Comment: I also tried Invalidate and refresh and neither command worked.

Comment: Both Invalidate and Refresh will lead to paint cycles. Perhaps your owner draw code has a fault. You didn't present an SSCCE. Also, what type is TopFormmlcmpStatusPanel1? I've assumed it is TStatusBar. Is that correct?

Comment: It was a TStatusBar.  The Status bar works correctly initially but when you change colors it does not refresh.